# Зачем нужен класс FilterInputStream?

Tags: java, архитектура

Просмотрев документацию и исходный код класса [`FilterInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FilterInputStream.html), а также код его наследников, возник вопрос: зачем вообще нужен этот класс?

Т.к. этот класс не является источником данных, не выполняет никакой полезной работы, то вероятно единственная цель его существования - решение каких-то архитектурных проблем.

Как я сейчас понимаю - система ввода/вывода java.io использует паттерн декоратор. Если классам наследникам `FilterInputStream` необходимо делегировать часть поведения потоку ввода, ссылку на который они принимают у себя в конструкторе, они не обращаются к методам `FilterInputStream`, а вызывают эти методы сразу по этой ссылке. Единственная вещь в `FilterInputStream`, которая используется всеми его наследниками, это ссылочное поле `protected volatile InputStream in`. Но ведь это всего лишь одно единственное поле и совершенно не сложно объявить его в самих наследниках `FilterInputStream`.

Пожалуйста, скажите прав я или нет, и если нет — то в чем я ошибаюсь или что я не учел.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Единственная вещь в `FilterInputStream`, которая используется всеми его наследниками, это ссылочное поле protected volatile InputStream in.

По порядку, все что делает `FilterInputStream`:

- содержит поле `in`, которое наследники могут использовать;
- объявляет конструктор, который принимает `InputStream` — каждому наследнику придется объявить хотя бы один конструктор и вызвать конструктор `FilterInputStream`;
- создает реализации по-умолчанию для всех методов [`InputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html), делегируя их вложенному потоку — девять методов, которые наследники могут не переопределять.

Т.е. если бы не было `FilterInputStream` каждому из его наследников пришлось бы:

- объявить поле для вложенного потока;
- принимать в конструкторе поток и инициализировать поле;
- создать шаблонные реализации для всех методов `InputStream` вида:

  ```
  public int read() {
       return in.read();
  }
  ```

За счет наличия шаблонных реализаций наследник может переопределить только те методы, поведение которых специфично для наследника. Например, [`CheckedInputStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/zip/CheckedInputStream.html) переопределяет три метода `FilterInputStream`, а наследует шесть.

В документации указано 11 наследников `FilterInputStream` (это только в стандартной библиотеке). Дублировать поле и инициализацию уже было бы плохо. Вставлять же в каждый из классов одинаковые делегирующие методы недопустимо.

Comment: @Regent Вы правы, я некорректно выразился. Внес поправки в этот пункт. Спасибо за замечание!

Comment: @Regent внес формулировку в ответ. Думаю, что теперь описание достаточно подробно.

Comment: @Regent этот пункт также переписал и уточнил.

Answer (score 3):

`FilterInputStream` - это декоратор для `InputStream`. Декораторов на `InputStream` существует целое множество: к примеру, `BufferedInputStream` и  `ZipOutputStream`.

Он реализует все те же методы, что и `InputStream`, который лежит в нём, но позволяет к ним добавить доп. функционал. Конкретно его используют для какой-либо модификации данных из `InputStream` (т.е. фильтрации).

Для лучшего понимания почитайте про [паттерн декоратор](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80_(%D1%88%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BD_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F))